# emcc static linking to cpp library

Tags: c++, static-linking, emscripten

I'm trying to compile my c++ code to .wasm, but my c++ code need `-Llibraries/bcrypt -lbcrypt` to be compiled, how i can include the library in emcc

my g++ compile command :

```
g++ --std=c++11 -lbcrypt bcrypt-wasm.cpp -Llibraries/bcrypt -lbcrypt -o bcrypt-wasm
```

My main c++ file :

```
#include "bcrypt/BCrypt.hpp"
#include <iostream>

int main(){
    BCrypt bcrypt;
    std::string password = "test";
    std::string hash = bcrypt.generateHash(password);

    std::cout << hash << std::endl;
    return 1;
}
```

Expected Result :

Compile my c++ code to .wasm binary

Comment: You may want to take a look at [this documentation page](https://github.com/kripken/emscripten/wiki/Linking).

Comment: @J-M.Gorius right, wasm running on sandbox-mode that doesn't have access to local libraries

Answer (score 1, accepted):

wasm running on sandbox-mode that doesn't have access to local libraries

more info : https://github.com/kripken/emscripten/wiki/Linking